# Understanding Mongo Timeouts on Save through Lock Percentage

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to understand how to better identify where the issue is with what i'm currently seeing.

Presently I am updating a collection through a cron, downloading information from a 3rd party vendor every 15 minutes (without issues). There are times when I need to do a 2 year refresh and is when I see this issue.

Incoming are about 300-600k results all which I'm using mongo->collection->save($item); on I have the _id for all results so that is being hit too for (what I thought) were quick inserts.

The document sizes aren't changing much and are rather small to begin with (12kb~).

I batch the downloads at about 200 per request to 3rd party server, format them, then insert them one at a time into mongo using save with safe insert set to true.

Right now when saves are happening it looks to up my lock percent to between 20-30%.  I'm wondering how to track down why this is happening as I believe it's the reason that I end up hitting a timeout (which is set to 100 seconds).

- Timeout Error: MongoCursorTimeoutException Object->cursor timed out (timeout: 100000, time left: 0:0, status: 0)
- Mongo Driver: Mongo Native Driver 1.2.6 (from PHP.net)

I'm currently on Mongo 2.2.1 with SSD drives and 16gb of ram.

Here is an example of the mongoStat operation that I follow while inserts are happening:

```
  insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res        faults                locked db               idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn  netOut  conn  set          repl    time 
  0       0     201    0      215     203     0       156g    313g     1.57g      7                    mydb:36.3%               0               0|0     0|0   892k   918k    52    a-cluster    PRI     10:04:36
```

I have a primary with a secondary setup and an arb fronting them (per documentation suggestions), using PHP to do my inserts.

any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Thank you so much for your time

**Update**

I store all items in a "MongoDoc" as there are times that formatting on each of the elements is needed, upon batching these items in there I get the data out and insert as

```
$mongoData = $mongoSpec->getData();
try {
    foreach($mongoData as $insert) {
        $this->collection_instance->save($insert);
        $count++;
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getTrace());
    exit;
}
```

I will say that I have removed safe writes and I've seen a drastic reduction in timeout's occurring, so as for now I'm chalking it up to that (unless there is something wrong with the insert..)

Thank you for your time and thoughts.

Comment: `MongoCursorTimeoutException` occurs when you use a cursor to retrieve data from the results of a previous query after 100 seconds have passed since the creation of the cursor.  So you shouldn't see that on an insert.  What's the statement that's throwing that exception?

Comment: It times out on doing a safe save method call; when I'm inserting one new document with a list of a handful other documents to be inserted.

Comment: Can you include some code please?  Something doesn't seem right here.  By the way, you say you are getting documents in batches of 200 - how are you getting them - are they in a file?  Or another DB?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting the PHP max execution limit?  Which Mongo library are you using?  I was using FuelPHP's MongoDb library, and it would take nearly 1 second for only ~50 inserts (because each write was a confirmed, fsync'd operation), so this doesn't surprise me. My solution was to fsync and write confirm only at certain intervals, which gives much better performance, with reasonable assurance that nothing went wrong.

More info:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/fsync/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#write-concern

Comment: Thank you for your response; I'm currently using the Mongo 1.2.6 native driver as seen on php.net.  The exact error message I was seeing was: cursor timed out (timeout: 100000, time left: 0:0, status: 0). Not certain if the above solution still works? Would switching to the FuelPHP library require updating the code for the calls it uses rather than the Mongo driver? Thank you!

Comment: Fuel's is just a wrapper for the native driver, so no need to switch.  The write concern and fsync issues should still apply.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the information; I'll investigate and report back.

Comment: Thanks for the documentation on this, just so I'm understanding then; you're writing with safe off and turning fsync's 60 second interval off, then every x writes issue an fsync=true write? Or would you be doing it as a command issued after doing a handful of writes. Also, not really sure how to determine the X value here.  Again thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Why do you think a reasonable lock % of 20-30 for full speed inserts has anything to do with cursors timing out? That lock percentage should actually be higher since in theory it should be completely occupied by your writes. I don't understand why you're getting cursor timeout errors if you're not doing anything that involves cursors (inserts certainly do not). The PHP driver code that throws this exception isn't clear and seems to throw this exception whenever select() returns 0 which may result in this error being thrown incorrectly but I'm not familiar enough with the code to be sure.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet I guess it's when I noticed things breaking. The lock percent would hit up and and it was really the first step I was attempting to take in order to debug what was going on.  The error always said it was failing on the save which is what was confusing to me.

Comment: @Petrogad, It is confusing in the sense that a save() should not result in a cursor to timeout in the first place. It might be that the error is thrown when it shouldn't but obviously it's slightly more likely that you're doing something that is causing an actual cursor timeout (which, again, shouldn't be the save)

Comment: I completely agree; however I just started seeing this issue as I added more data to my dbs and collections.  I'm now wondering due to Iandons answer that if the safe write is causing to much lag time and if multiple instances are being updated at the same time something is causing a lag time. I really don't know how to better debug the scenario as right now I'm catching all exceptions and it's throwing the cursor exception on a safe save (yet only occasionally) which is why I thought to look at mongostat while it was happening.

Comment: I'm only going off my experience with Fuel's wrapper class, which defaults to fsync'ing every insert or update.  Every 60 seconds shouldn't be a problem, but you shouldn't have to write confirm every single insert; that will definitely affect performance.  But, as @RemonvanVliet is saying, the cursor timeout shouldn't have anything to do with inserts.

Comment: you should never use write concern fsync - you should use journal safe if you want to make sure it's flushed to disk but since you have a replica set w:2 is probably more durable than that anyway.  However, the cursor that's timing out is not writing - you are reading something from a cursor and that's what's timing out.  You haven't posted any of your code - could you post the relevant lines?  Are you sure you're not doing any reads?